# How to display specified table column for Error Number: 22001/8152 SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated?

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, sql-server-2017

I get Error Number: 22001/8152 
`SQL [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data` `would be truncated.`
that means 
one of my columns in the source table is bigger than my destination columns.
unfortunately that messsage not display which column is it who , I work with much table columns structure it is about 161 column. I think checking one by one my parameter value and column size is not good deal. 
is there fastest way to do that?
this is my inssert query look like

```
INSERT INTO "my_db"."dbo"."my_table" ("Indeks_Keterpaduan", "NA", "admin_pembiayaan", "adopt_b2", "aktivitas_id", "aktivitas_nama", "assessment", "catatan", "dba_", "dlokasi", "dukungan_kawasan", "ikk_id", "ikk_nama", "ikp_id", "ikp_nama", "isu_strategis_id", "isu_strategis_nama", "jaringan_jalan", "jenis_arahan", "jenis_kegiatan", "jenis_kontrakID", "jenis_kontrakNama", "jenis_kotrakKode", "jenis_sub_aktivitas", "kabkot", "kawasan_nama", "kecamatan_id", "kegiatan_id", "kegiatan_nama", "ket_lokasi", "keterangan", "kewenangan", "kode_ssp", "kode_sspn", "kpk", "kws_kode", "outcome_id", "outcome_nama", "output_id", "output_nama", "param_a", "param_b", "param_c", "param_d", "param_e", "param_total", "phln", "politik_anggaran", "prioritas", "program_id", "program_nama", "provinsi_id", "rc_DED", "rc_DEDalokasi", "rc_DEDsatuan", "rc_DEDvol", "rc_Dokling", "rc_Doklingalokasi", "rc_Doklingsatuan", "rc_Doklingvol", "rc_FS", "rc_FSalokasi", "rc_FSsatuan", "rc_FSvol", "rc_dokptanah", "rc_kesesuaian_rtrw", "rc_konstruksi", "rc_konstruksialokasi", "rc_konstruksisatuan", "rc_konstruksivol", "rc_lahan", "rc_lahanalokasi", "rc_lahansatuan", "rc_lahanvol", "rc_masterplan", "rc_pnp1", "rc_pnp2", "rc_proposalpnp", "rc_rdtr", "rc_rdtralokasi", "rc_rdtrsatuan", "rc_rdtrvol", "rc_rispam", "rc_rispamalokasi", "rc_rispamsatuan", "rc_rispamvol", "rc_rp2kpkp", "rc_rp2kpkpalokasi", "rc_rp2kpkpsatuan", "rc_rp2kpkpvol", "rc_rtbl", "rc_rtblalokasi", "rc_rtblsatuan", "rc_rtblvol", "rc_sddt", "rc_skbup", "rc_skbupalokasi", "rc_skbupsatuan", "rc_skbupvol", "rc_skma", "rc_skt", "rc_spb", "rc_spd", "rc_spp", "readines", "rmp", "rpm", "sa1thn_id", "sajp_id", "sastra_id", "sastra_uraian", "satuan_output", "sbsn", "score_admin_pembiayaan", "score_jaringan_jalan", "score_kpk", "score_politik_anggaran", "score_readines", "sinkronisasi", "status", "status_konreg", "status_rakor", "status_verifikasi", "sub_aktivitas", "subkawasan_nama", "suboutput_id", "suboutput_nama", "sumber_arahan", "sumber_dana", "sumber_data_lainnya", "sumber_input_data", "tahun_anggaran", "tapisan", "time_create", "time_update", "total_score", "unit_id", "unit_nama", "uraian_ssp", "uraian_sspn", "user_create", "user_update", "volume", "waa_", "wab_", "wac_", "wba_", "wbb_", "wbc_", "wca_", "wcb_", "wcc_", "wda_", "wdb_", "wdc_", "wps_kode", "wps_nama", "x", "y")values (value1,value2,...,value (n))
```

Comment: if you can run up SQL Server 2019 locally  you'll get the exact table/column/value in the error msg.....

Comment: No I can't upgrade/instal sql server version to higher version because curent version used by other development project I am woried about another compatibility isues in my system

Comment: i don't mean upgrade for good; just to find the error. you can install side-by-side instances of sql server.

Comment: that is good Idea,I will try thank you very much @Mitch Wheat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, prior to SQL Server 2019, there's no easy way to pinpoint the cause of error msg 8152 "String or Binary data would be truncated".

While not an ideal solution (but it could save your sanity!), what you could do is install a local, side-by-side preview instance of SQL Server 2019, and run your application against it just to get the exact cause of the error!

Ref: [String or Binary data would be truncated: replacing the infamous error 8152](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-replacing-the-infamous-error-8152/)